# Conduit streaming monad state

Tags: haskell, yield, conduit, statet

I have a conduit pipeline whose monad includes state. At one point I'd like to have a conduit that streams the state to the following ones (this is a simplified version of what I actually need).

But I have trouble making this. The following example only streams the state once, from the yield:

```
import Conduit (ConduitM, yield)
import Control.Monad.Except (Except)
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy (StateT, get)

type CondState = String
type CondMonad = StateT CondState (Except String)

passState :: ConduitM i CondState CondMonad ()
passState = do
  state <- get
  yield state
```

If I run

```
runExcept $ (runStateT . runConduit $ yieldMany [(1::Int)..] .| passState .| sinkList) "state"
```

I get

```
Right (["state"], "state")
```

rather than the infinite list that I'm aiming for in the first tuple position.

In the actual application the state changes as the conduit streams.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out a solution is something like

```
passState = mapMC $ \_ -> do
  state <- get
  return state
```